# how to show the checked checkbox into a messagebox in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, checkbox

I was wondering how to do like the below image:

[image]

In 'Summary' (on right), under 'You purchased:', I want to list the options user has checked in 'Available Books' (on left)

```
private void btnPurchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string BOOKS;
        MessageBox.Show("You Purchase :\n"
                +"\t" + BOOKS + "\n" //checked checkbox shows here
                + "The selected payment method is : " + payment
                + "\nYour comment about us : " + txtKomen.Text);
    }
```

I use the code above, and it only show the first checked checkbox, how to add another checked checkbox in message box?

Should I use an array for the `BOOKS`? If that is the way, how to loop it into the messagebox?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
private void btnPurchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] BOOKS;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var item in BOOKS)
    {
        sb.Append($"\t{item}");
        sb.AppendNewLine();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("You Purchase :\n"
        + sb.ToString()//checked checkbox shows here
        + "The selected payment method is : " + payment
        + "\nYour comment about us : " + txtKomen.Text);
}
```

Though I'm not sure if `.Append` and `.AppendNewLine()` exist in `StringBuilder`, they might have a different name in any case Visual Studio should tell you the correct name.

Comment: there is an error **Use of unassigned local variable 'BOOKS'**

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string books = "";
    foreach (var itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        books += itemChecked + " ";
    }
    MessageBox.Show("You Purchase :\n" + "\t" + books + "\n");

}
```

> If you want to use this you have to add CheckedListBox on your form.

Comment: It works btw thank you so much, but i need to ask something, I need to add "\t" for showing a tab before the title of the book, where should i place the "\t" ?

Comment: Did this image helpful for you?

Comment: Absolutely yes, but if we want to add the book's price for an example, can a listcheckbox do that?

Comment: You can use GridView for this.

Comment: Pardon me, but how to do that? I'm completely new with this language, maybe u can show me how to do that?